# s3 pre-signed url Javascript Code not Returning Full url

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to generate pre-signed url's for files in my s3 bucket so that users of my site will not have the links to the actual files. I have been trying to use this code below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'AKIAVXSBEXAMPLE', secretAccessKey: 'EXAMPLE5ig8MDGZD8p8iTj7t3KEXAMPLE'})

    // Tried with and without this. Since s3 is not region-specific, I don't
    // think it should be necessary.
    AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'})

    const myBucket = 'bucketexample'
    const myKey = 'example.png'
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5

    const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: myBucket,
        Key: myKey,
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
    })
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("url", url); }, 3000);
    console.log("url:", url)
```

However all it returns is this: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"

I have also tried using this code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {Bucket: 'bucketexample', Key: 'example.png'};
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
       console.log('The URL is', url);
    });
```

Which does not return anything. Does anyone know why they are not returning a working urls?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same issue... I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Thank you, I shall let you know if I find anything.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue. When the AWS SDK returns https://s3.amazonaws.com/ it is because of the machine not having the proper permissions. This can be frustrating, and I think that AWS should return a descriptive error message instead of just returning the wrong url.

I would recommend that you configure your AWS credentials for your machine or give it a role in AWS. Although you should be able to put in your credentials via code like you did in your code snippet, that didn't work for me as well for whatever reason.

What worked for me was updating my machine's default AWS credentials or adding proper roles for the deployed servers.

Comment: I am doing this in an HTML element in a browser rather than in a machine. Does that differ from your solution?

Comment: Yes, pre-signed URL's requires permissions from AWS. Using credentials on the frontend would expose them to anyone that looked at the website code, so that is definitely not secure and something you shouldn't do. Also, if you are using AWS roles or something like that then it still wouldn't work because the html and javascript code would run in the user's browser, not the actual AWS resource that has the role. In short, you need to generate the pre-signed URLs on a backend server that has the correct AWS credentials for the SDK to properly run, or the correct role set by you on AWS. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue where I was getting incomplete signed URL like  when I used  :

```
    let url = await s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: s3FileLocation,
  Expires: ttlInSeconds,
});
```

Then I used the Promise function instead :

```
// I used it inside an async function

let url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("getObject", {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: s3FileLocation,
  Expires: ttlInSeconds,
});
```

And it returned complete signed URL.

**Note:**

In case you receive this message on tryign to access the object using signed URL.

```
    <Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.</Message>
```

Then use this while initializing s3 :

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({"signatureVersion":"v4"});
```